# i do not seem to understand why im having these undefined index notices

Tags: php

what is causing this undefined index error or notices im getting on my page

```
Notice: Undefined index: start_date in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\admin panel\daily.php on line 97

Notice: Undefined index: balance in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\admin panel\daily.php on line 98
```

the code on line 97 and 98 is

```
echo '<td>' . $row['start_date'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['balance'] . '</td>';
```

this is my whole code

```
<?php

include'includes/connect.php';
 $allowedSorts = array('start_date', 'balance');

    $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : '';
    $result = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%m-%d') AS 'month and day',balance as amount FROM `aggrement`";
    if(in_array($sort, $allowedSorts)){
         $result .= " ORDER BY {$sort}";
    }

    $result = mysql_query($result) or die(mysql_error());


echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr>
<th><a href='view.php?sort=start_date'>month and day</th>
<th><a href='view.php?sort=balance'>Amount Paid</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['start_date'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['balance'] . '</td>';
echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Just because there is no result for `start_date` and `balance` in your array `$row`..

Comment: Read your `SELECT` statement and pay close attention to keyword `AS` and what follows after that.

Comment: var_dump your row and see if it actually has anything in it..

Comment: `i do not seem to understand` Does that mean you don't understand whether you understand or not? I'm confused!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting alias name for each one, so you can't access them with default columnname.

You must get them with alias name. Like

`$row["month and day"]` and `$row["amount"]`.